# Esistono prefissi flessionali nella lingua italiana?

Tags: grammar

Mi sono imbarcato in qualche ricerca per capire la nomenclatura delle varie parti che costituiscono una parola, fondamentalmente perché non conoscevo la differenza tra suffisso e desinenza.

Poi l'ho capita. Però mi è rimasta una curiosità.

Su [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/suffisso/) ho letto che la desinenza è un tipo suffisso, precisamente un (o il?) suffisso flessionale, che è distinto dal suffisso tematico.

Mi viene allora spontaneo chiedermi: esistono *pre*fissi flessionali, in italiano? E *in*fissi flessionali?

---

Il dubbio, devo dire, mi è stato stimolato da una frase che ho letto sulla pagina Wikipedia di [desinenza](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desinenza):

> Il significato tradizionale del termine si è assestato nell'identificare quella porzione della parola che risulta variabile nella **flessione** e che **generalmente coincide con la sua parte finale**.

Quindi mi sono detto: non è che ci sono casi in cui la flessione avviene a inizio parola o in mezzo ad essa, nel qual caso essa è operata tramite prefisso o infisso rispettivamente, invece che suffisso? Data la sua funzione sarebbe però un prefisso/infisso flessionale, proprio come il suffisso adibito alla flessione è suffisso flessionale, meglio noto come desinenza.

Comment: Non sono sicurissimo di capire compiutamente la domanda, quindi intanto lo scrivo come commento. Risponderebbe alla tua domanda un caso come “vede” e “vide”, dove una parte della distinzione (presente rispetto a passato remoto) è data da una lettera in mezzo alla parola?

Comment: Sembra di no secondo Treccani: *in italiano i prefissi esprimono infatti solo valori derivazionali (➔ derivazione) e, a differenza dei suffissi, non sono usati per marcare la ➔ flessione.*  https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/prefissi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)

Comment: @Hachi, sembra che quanto hai trovato risponda alla mia domanda. Almeno secondo la visione di Treccani.

Comment: @DaG, immagino che quello sia un caso di _in_-fisso flessionale, piuttosto che _pre_-fisso?

Comment: @DaG, ho leggermente ampliato la domanda.

Comment: Grazie, Enlico. nella tua domanda rientra anche il mio esempio vede/vide, dove non si tratta neppure di un infisso, ma di una variazione della vocale tematica?

Comment: @DaG,  dalla mia prima risposta al tuo commento si dovrebbe capire che ho confuso il concetto di vocale tematica con quello di infisso. Non so nemmeno, a questo punto, se esistano infissi in italiano. In ogni caso, la risposta è no, perché, per dirla in "matematichese", ho posto la domanda perché immaginavo di poter riempire con un esempio quante più punti possibili del "prodotto cartesiano" [prefisso, infisso, suffisso] x [tematico, flessionale]. Forse questa matrice è mezza vuota in italiano?

Comment: Ho capito, grazie del chiarimento in termini insiemistici!

Comment: @Enlico Credo che tecnicamente vedo/vidi sia un caso di *umlaut*, che non mi risulta si qualifichi come un infisso (per me un infisso dovrebbe essere come vorbereiten/vorzubereiten in tedesco etc)